# Django Aggregation of values queryset

Tags: django, django-aggregation

I have a ValuesQuerySet called `data`.

I am trying to get a summary count of all the type for each object

`data.values('type')` produces this output:

```
[{'type': u'internal'}, {'type': u'internal'}, {'type': u'external'}, {'type': u'external'}]
```

I want to get a breakdown like this (there can be more then just 'internal' and 'external' as choices. This could be up to 20 different types:

```
internal: 2
external: 2
```

I'm trying this but it's just returning a empty dictionary...

```
data.values('type').aggregate(Count('type'))
```

Annotate is producing undesirbale results as well:

```
data.values('type').annotate(Count('type'))


[{'type': u'internal', 'type_count': 1}, {'type': u'internal', 'type_count': 1}, {'type': u'external', 'type_count': 1}, {'type': u'external', 'type_count': 1}]
```

Models.py

```
class Purchase(models.Model):    

    type = models.ForeignKey(Types)
```

Comment: What is the type of `data`, what is the type of `data.values('type')`?

Comment: It is a ValuesQuerySet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 lists = ModelName.objects.values('type').annotate(count=Count('type'))
```

In html:

```
 {% for list in lists %}
     {{list.type}} - {{list.count}}<br/>
 {% endfor %}
```

Test:

```
 {{lists}}
 //don't use forloop yet. This will tests if the above query produce data or it is empty
```

**UPDATED:**

```
def view_name(request):
    lists = ModelName.objects.values_list('type', flat=True).distinct()
    types = []
    for list in lists:
        type_count = ModelName.objects.filter(type=list.type).count()
        types.append({'type': list.type, 'count': type_count})

    return render(request, 'page.html', {
            'types': types,
    })

{% for type in types %}
    {{type.type}} - {{type.count}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That is still returning an empty dictionary for me. I have almost 500k objects in this model but nothing was produced from that query

Comment: @Austin try to change aggregate to annotate. After that in your template test like this {{lists}}, don't use forloop. It's for testing so that we will know if there are query

Comment: I do get somewhat desired results from using annotate. Is the problem having a ValuesQuerySet compared to QuerySet? I would like to try to avoid another database call as my 'data' variable comes from using a query that uses a filter and an exclude. I then get the values() of particular fields from there. I guess I'm just trying to understand why my original code did not work.

Comment: I added annotate to my original post and displayed it's result. Not sure why it's displaying this way

Comment: because the query filter only one model. It would be easy if the type is in another model. That's why I request for your model codes

Comment: model posted. It's all coming from within the same model

Comment: this is difficult. I will search for other solution for this

Comment: I apologize. I have two different things I am summarizing. One is working, the other, is not. The one that is not is indeed related to another model

Comment: @austin i updated my answer try it. and about what you have said i thought it's not related to other model

Answer (score 1):

They are several approach, let's supose you want results in a dictionary, the easy way is:

```
results = { 'internal': data.filter( value = 'internal'  ).count(),
            'external': data.filter( value = 'external'  ).count() }
```

For few queryset you can use itertools, this translate work from database layer to django tier. That means that it is only a solution for little querysets.

```
from itertools import groupby
results = groupby(data.all(), lambda x: x.type)
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that there can be more than two choices. Up to 20 aside from 'internal' and 'external'